# How can one prevent page breaks between Tables in SQL Reporting Services 2005?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, page-break

I've been developing an SSRS 2005 report (a form letter) that contains two tables.  The first "table" uses DataSet "A" to populate address fields on letterhead.

The second table uses DataSet "B" to display a basic list of records that pertain to the addressed party.

Even though the two tables are within the same page and all PageBreak* properties are set to "False", SSRS renders the report as two pages.

How can I force both tables to render in series, without any page breaks?

Am I missing something, here?  Are you not supposed to include two tables on a single report on the same page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please test this approach :

1- put a rectangle in your report.

2- put your tables in this rectangle.

maybe this approach solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a List control too (if the rectangle doesn't work out).

Drag both tables into the list control, enable the list property "fit this on one page if possible", cross your fingers, and preview the report.

Edit: the List control may require you to select a data set, in which case you'd be hosed...sorry, I should have read more thoroughly before posting.